# Matplotlib bar3d non-linear axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a set of non-linearly distributed data points depending on two variables, which I am plotting in a `matplotlib` 3D bar chart as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

x_values = [4, 8, 16, 32, 4, 8, 16, 32, 4, 8, 16, 32, 4, 8, 16, 32]
y_values = [64, 64, 64, 64, 256, 256, 256, 256, 512, 512, 512, 512, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024]
z_values = np.random.rand(16)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.bar3d(x_values, y_values, np.zeros_like(z_values), 1, 1, z_values)
ax.axes.set_xticks(x_values)
ax.axes.set_yticks(y_values)
plt.show()
```

[image: Unmodified bar chart]

The resulting plot naturally shows the non-linearity in x- and y-values. However, I would like to arrange the values in a way such that those x- and y-values can be interpreted as categorical values. Essentially the plot I desire is depicted in the following picture, but with x and y axes reading `[4 8 16 32]` and `[64 256 512 1024]`, respectively.

[image: Desired plot]

How does one go about achieving this categorical representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.unique(..., return_inverted=True)` to map each value in your `x_values` and `y_values` array to a number, then it is just a matter of replacing the labels on the axes with the corresponding values

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

np.random.seed(1234)
x_values = [4, 8, 16, 32, 4, 8, 16, 32, 4, 8, 16, 32, 4, 8, 16, 32]
y_values = [64, 64, 64, 64, 256, 256, 256, 256, 512, 512, 512, 512, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024]
z_values = np.random.rand(16)

x_labels, x_pos = np.unique(x_values, return_inverse=True)
y_labels, y_pos = np.unique(y_values, return_inverse=True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.bar3d(x_pos-0.5, y_pos-0.5, np.zeros_like(z_values), 1, 1, z_values)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x_labels)))
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(y_labels)))
ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! Icing on the cake if you can point me to a way on how I could shift the bars in such a way that the labels are at their 'center'. That's something I took forever to master for 2d plots, I assume that should also be possible in this case?

Comment: simply shift the values of `x_pos` and `y_pos` by 0.5. I've edited my answer

Comment: The hardest to find answers are the simplest ones, thank you!